# How to generate subsrcipt in formula with text format in gnuplot, with esplatex terminal?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I have tried with the following code:

```
set term epslatex size 1.3, 1.3 standalone color colortext 9
set output "./test.tex"
set size square 1.3, 1.3

set xtics 1
set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "#470024" lw 3

#plot
set yrange [0: 1]
set xrange [0: 5]
set ytics 0.2
set border 1+2+4+8
set ylabel '$y_{\rm wait}$' offset 0.8,0,0
set xlabel '$t$' offset 0,0.5,0
plot exp(-(x)**0.3)  w l ls 1 lw 3 notitle

set output
```

The current output.
[image]

**The expected ylabel**: the subscript is a normal text, instead of an italic form.

(the following part is added 2 days later)

Thanks to your help, I updated the code:

```
set term epslatex size 1.3, 1.3 standalone color colortext 8
set output "./text.tex"
set size square 1.5, 1.3

set xtics 1
set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "#470024" lw 3

#plot
set yrange [0: 1]
set xrange [0: 5]
set ytics 1
set border 1+2+4+8
set ylabel '$y_\textrm{wait}$' offset 0.8,0,0
set xlabel '$t$' offset 0,0.5,0
plot exp(-(x)**0.3)  w l ls 1 lw 3 title "$N_\textrm{wait}$"

set output
```

[image]

Now the ylabel is exactly what I want, but I can not obtain the correct subscript for the legend.

Comment: Do you have to use epslatex terminal? Since I have other issues with eps files and my LaTeX installation, I tried with cairolatex terminal creating a PDF and I don't see this behaviour, `_wait` is not italics.

Comment: @theozh Yes I have to use epslatex. All other formula can work only I set epslatex as terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with gnuplot, it is an issue with using the deprecated `\rm` with a modern LaTeX.  Use instead `\textup` or `\textrm`.  For a more complete discussion, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151897/always-textrm-never-rm-a-counterexample

gnuplot command:

```
set ylabel '$y_{\textup {wait}}$' offset 0.8,0,0
```

**Edit**

If the example below does not work for you then we'll need more information - gnuplot version, latex version, etc

```
set term epslatex standalone
set out 'font.tex'
set yrange [0: 1]
set xrange [0: 5]
set ytics 0.2
set border 1+2+4+8
set ylabel '$y_{\textrm {wait}}$' offset 0.8,0,0
set xlabel '$t$' offset 0,0.5,0
plot exp(-(x)**0.3)  w l ls 1 lw 3 title '$Math_{\textup {Roman}}$'
```

[image]

Comment: `\textrm` works for the ylabel! But it seems in the key `\textrm` or `\textup` can not generate the expected form. Could you give a suggestion?

Comment: I think you need single quotes around the title string so that the `\t` is passed through to latex rather than being interprete as a <tab>.

Comment: Yes, single quotes should be used. After I changed to single quotes, it works. The problem is solved.